# VBA - not referring to function correctly

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and do not know whether my function is being correctly utilized or whether the function itself is flawed.

My subprocedure is as follows:

```
 Sub InsertEquitiesBonds()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Integer
    Set ws = Worksheets("PnL")
    ws.Range("B3").Value = "Equities"
    Worksheets("SummaryEquities").Range("MarketsEquities").Copy ws.Range("C4")

    Dim LastUsedCell As Range
    Set LastUsedCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)

    LastUsedCell.Offset(1, -1).Value = "Bonds"
    Worksheets("SummaryBonds").Range("MarketsBonds").Copy LastUsedCell.Offset(2, 0)  
    For i = 4 To ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = OurFees(Range("C" & i))
    Next i
    Range("A1").Select
    End Sub
```

As described in the `InsertEquitiesBonds()` the code works until I have to use the function `OurFees` that it actually just ignores. This leads me to the question am I not referring to my function correctly or if I am, is the function inevitably flawed?

`OurFees()` function is described as the following:

```
Function OurFees(rng As Range)
If rng.Value.IsEmpty = True Then
OurFees = ""
Else
    Dim BasisPoint, VolMin, VolDistr As Range
    If Columns("B").Find("Bonds").Row < rng.Row Then
        With Worksheets("CheatSheet_Bonds")
            BasisPoint = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A5:E6"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(rng, Range("C5:C6"), 0), 3)
            VolMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A5:E6"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(rng, Range("D5:D6"), 0), 4)
        End With
        With Worksheets("SummaryBonds")
            VolDistr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("B12:C50"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(rng, Range("B12:B50"), 0), 2)
            OurFees = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("D9") * BasisPoint, VolMin) * Range("D8") * VolDistr
        End With
    Else
        With Worksheets("CheatSheet_Equities")
            BasisPoint = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A4:D21"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(rng, Range("B4:B21"), 0), 3)
            VolMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A4:D21"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(rng, Range("B4:B21"), 0), 4)
        End With
        With Worksheets("SummaryEquities")
            VolDistr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("B12:C40"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(rng, Range("B12:B40"), 0), 2)
            OurFees = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("D9") * BasisPoint, VolMin) * Range("D8") * VolDistr
        End With
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Comment: 1) I guess if you went in proper detail then the function definition would be `Function OurFees(rng as Range)` 2) Assuming 1), then your function wants an object (namely a `Range` object) parameter while `OurFees(Cells(i, 3).Value)` is supplying it a Variant. -> you should use `OurFees(Cells(i, 3))` but the given detail is inadequate to know if it's the final word...

Comment: Ok, I'll expand on the function

Comment: Then I confirm: change `OurFees(Cells(i, 3).Value)` to `OurFees(Cells(i, 3))`. But you'd better qualify that range up to its worksheet, too (e.g.: `OurFees(ws.Cells(i, 3))`. And you have to set `OurFees = ...` somewhere in the `Else` clause...

Comment: I think the real problem lies in the function, namely, is  it be possible that `Match` cannot be used in vba?

Comment: @user9078057 `WorksheetFunction.Match` is fine - not sure why OP is using `WorksheetFunction.Index` instead of just `Range.Cells` though (e.g. `Range("A5:E6").Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(rng, Range("C5:C6"), 0), 3)`) - I always prefer to error-handle `WorksheetFunction.Match` in case it doesn't find a match too

Comment: @user9078057, step through your code upon entering the function (place a breakpoint - F9 - at `ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = OurFees(Range("C" & i)` code line), go on line by line pressing F8 and use Immediate Window (CTRL-G to pop it out) to query relevant variables values (e.g.: type `?Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(rng, Range("B12:B40"), 0)` to see the outcome of the match operation before having the code execute it)

Comment: How can you tell `OurFees` is not being called? Set a breakpoint at that line, execute `InsertEquitiesBonds` and wait for the execution to reach the breakpoint. Then proceed to manually execute your code with F8. This should give you an idea what's happening.

Comment: @DisplayName We had the same idea, apparently. ;) Also, don't forget to mention the Local window (Menu: View) - I find it tremendously helpful.

Comment: @Inarion, I forgot but you didn't...now user9078057 knows about everything she needs

Comment: @Inarion I've now defined `BasisPoint As Long` but I keep on getting "Type mismatch" when I get to the following line: BasisPoint = Range("A4:D21").Cells(Application.Match(rng, Range("B4:B21"), 0), 3).Value` . Surely it returns a range so then I need to add `.Value`

Comment: @user9078057 `WorksheetFunction.Match` is a function returning a `Double`. When addressing cells via `.Cells(row, column)` you need integers for `row` and `column`.

Comment: I realize that but `BasisPoint = Range("A4:D21").Cells(Application.Match(rng, Range("B4:B21"), 0), 3).Value` gives me a type mismatch

Comment: @user9078057 That's exactly what I was pointing to. `.Cells(Integer, Integer)` doesn't like a `Double` for an `Integer`.

Comment: @Inarion @DisplayName Oh ok, Thanks! And last question: going thorugh the code line by line as you describe as well as Converting the `Application.Match` into an `Integer` I get the following value for `CInt(Application.Match(rng, Range("B4:B21"), 0))= 2042 ` Now I am aware that this is an error code for `#N/A`, however, I do not know why the values would be #N/A as  the values are readily available

Comment: @user9078057 Not sure I'm following. I'm getting an Error 1004 if `.Match` can't find anything. There's no magical conversion from error codes to integers happening (for me).

Comment: There appears to be a difference between `Application.Match` and `WorksheetFunction.Match` (apart from the fact that the latter is documented and the former isn't): `Application.Match` will return an error code, while `WorksheetFunction.Match` will throw a runtime error. In this case, you'll have to find out why `.Match` won't find your value. We can't tell with the information given.

Answer (score 1):

try with below

```
For i = 4 To ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = OurFees(Range("C" & i))
Next i
```